# Inno Setup show space required by installation on custom folder select page

Tags: inno-setup

I'm creating a custom `TInputDirWizardPage` in Inno Setup to ask for multiple installation folders from the user.

On the default input directory page the component named `DiskSpaceLabel` is visible showing how much space is required by the setup. But it's not visible on my custom `TInputDirWizardPage`. Is there a way to display it?

Comment: Are you using the standard "select directory" page? Or do you use only your custom page?

Comment: Only my custom page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not using the standard *"Select Destination Location"* page, you can simply move the `DiskSpaceLabel` to your custom page by changing its `Parent`:

```pascal
var
  DirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  DirPage := CreateInputDirPage(
    wpSelectDir, SetupMessage(msgWizardSelectDir), '', '', False, '');
  { add directory input page items }
  DirPage.Add('Path to Apache:');
  DirPage.Add('Path to PHP:');
  DirPage.Add('Path to Server Files:');

  WizardForm.DiskSpaceLabel.Parent := DirPage.Surface;
end;
```

[image]